# Is there a generic solution in Java for mutual exclusion between threads based on a generated key?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Lets say I have a `FooClass`, which has an `id` with type long:

```
public class FooClass {
    long id;
}
```

There is a method in whatever class with similar signature:

```
public void shouldBeSynchronizedForAFooClassId(long fooClassId) {
    //does something
}
```

What could I do:

- I could make the method synchronized, but it is an unneccessary bottleneck, since `FooClass` with `id` 1 and `FooClass` with `id` 2 can run parallel without problem.
- I could generate a string with the id and make an intern() of it, and I could synchronize on that *(I don't like this idea)*
- Synchronizing on Longs is also not a good idea.
- I could create a `Map` with id as key and a monitored `Object` as value. This case I have to suffer with registering the number of threads using the same monitored Object to be able to cleanup the monitored Objects as soon as they are not used by any thread anymore.

I thought, there must be a readymade solution like:

- There could be a LockManager or whatever, which is generized with a type (in my fall with Long above). It could provide a runSafely(Runnable run) method, which would do the mutual exclusion encapsulated, including generating the monitor object if needed, and removing it after. Of course I have to get the id inside this runSafely as well.

Is there something like this out of the box in some library?

Comment: Can't you synchronize on the FooClass instance itself (assuming ach ID maps to a single corresponding FooClass instance)? Otherwise, look at Guava's Striped: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html

Comment: @JBNizet synchronizing on FooClass does not help, since several FooClass instances can be present in the JVM (coming from frontend, loaded by persistence layer, changed or used by different sessions)

Comment: Then Guava's Striped is probably what you want.

Comment: @JBNizet Guava's Striped seems to be interesting. Thanks for mentioning it. +1

Comment: @JBNizet If you give an answer with striped, I will accept it. Just go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, as far as I know, any ready-made solution to the problem you're facing in the JDK.

But Guava has [Striped](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html), which does almost what you want. It doesn't associate a lock per ID, but rather a lock per "stripe" of IDs. That should be sufficient to avoid contention.

Answer (score 1):

The tools you need are available but you'll have to assembly the solution yourself, e.g., [a map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of [ReentrantLocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Comment: With a simple map of Locks I have to take care of removing the locks as soon as no thread needs them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `long id`, you could have `ID id;` where `ID` is a class that you define.  Then you can simply lock the `id` object.

Your ID class can have a numeric value, or whatever other attributes you find convenient.

Comment: If I have an ID class, it does not help at all against having two instances of ID with the same long id inside. Two objects for the same numeric id.

Comment: @GáborLipták, I'm assuming you would write code that does not do that.  My suggestion to define an `ID` class was not meant to solve the problem of how you assign IDs to `FooClass` instances:  It was meant to solve the problem of, a `long` is not a thing you can lock.

Comment: This way I would have to create and register the IDs from a singleton, which ends up in the problem of cleaning up instances, which are not in use anymore. Like I have written in my comment of my question above, FooClass instances are created in several places inside the application.